# Open Explorer - java

Tags: java, swing

In one of my java swing application, I am dynamically open windows share folder. Now I want to open it using explorer. So can you guys please help me out to solve it.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Java 6, the best way to do this is to use [`Desktop`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(path));
```

Comment: so the file like new File("file://192.168.1.100:/") ?

Comment: @fengye: You should be able to use just `Desktop.open(url)`.

Comment: how create the file Instance ? about the windows share's path

Comment: Most likely you would use the [UNC path](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/UNC_path#Uniform_Naming_Convention), so in this case `new File("\\\\192.168.1.100")`.  Also, you could use the [`#browse(URI)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)) method.

Comment: This does not work for opening explorer and pointing it to a specific file.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows (XP/Vista) the following code will work:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer /select,  " + folder);
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question accurately (as opposed to answering).

Comment: If the folder name contains space you will need to quote it: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer /select,\"" + folder + "\"");

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against this `.getRuntime()`... approach if you have a large application.  This approach forks the process, so if you are running this from a large program (e.g., within an application server) the fork can eat up your entire available RAM.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment on Tarlog's answer.